# Port sharing in WebListener

Tags: asp.net-core, weblistener

How to share a port with 2 services using WebListener in Asp.Net core.

I tried registering URL Prefixes as below,

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://machinename:8080/Service1 user=xxx listen=yes

netsh http add urlacl url=http://machinename:8080/Service2 user=xxx listen=yes
```

But while starting the second service with same 8080 port, i am getting below error.

```
fail: Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener[0]
      Start
Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException (0x80004005): The process cannot
access the file because it is being used by another process
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String uriPrefix, Int32
contextId)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
 urlGroup)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()
```

Here is the code

```
string baseAddress = "http://machinename:8080/Service1";
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseWebListener(options =>
{
  options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes =                                                                         
  Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
  options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
})
.UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls(baseAddress);

host = builder.Build();
```

Comment: What prefix values did you pass to WebListener? They need to exactly match what you specified in netsh.

Comment: posted code above

Comment: Try adding trailing slashes everywhere. http.sys is picky about that. WebListener adds them for you but netsh may not.

Comment: My bad, one of the service was still running in Kestrel engine. By changing that too WebListener, the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
.UseHttpSys(options =>
                {
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000");
                    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                })
```

use this
link: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpSysServer/blob/master/samples/SelfHostServer/Startup.cs

Comment: Please give always a little context to your answer. Pasting code combined with a weblink (which can get invalid at any time) could make it hard for other users to understand your solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details